# While loop working perfectly in Insertion sort, but For loop is not working as expected in place of while loop

Tags: c++, loops, sorting, insertion-sort

I tried using for loop, but it gives a wrong answer. When I used a while loop in its place the sorting is done as expected. Can someone help me debug?

Note : It doesn't throw an compilation error, just gives a wrong ans when using for loop. And I have tried running on different IDE's and even tried dry running the for loop, but I am unable to understand the problem here.

```cpp
//While loop
while(j >= 0 && arr[j] > element)
{
    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
    j = j - 1;
}

//For loop
for(; j >= 0; j--)
{
    if(arr[j] > element)
    {
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
    }
}
```

Full code if anyone needs

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;

class Solution
{
    public:
    vector<int> sortArr(vector<int> arr, int n)
    {
        int i, j, element;

        for(i = 1; i < n; i++)
        {
            element = arr[i];
            j = i - 1;

            while(j >= 0 && arr[j] > element)
            {
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
                j = j - 1;
            }

            /*for(  ; j >= 0 ; j--)
        {
            if(arr[j] > element){
                arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
            }    
            
        }*/

            arr[j + 1] = element;
        }

        return arr;
    }
};

int main()
{
    vector<int> s(4);
    for(int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        cin >> s[i];
    }

    Solution ob;
    vector<int> v = ob.sortArr(s, 4);

    for(auto i : v)
    {
        cout << i << ' ';
    }
    cout << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: The two loops are not equivalent.

Comment: The while loop terminates the first time `arr[j] <= element`, the for loop doesn't

Comment: Did you try to debug the code?

Comment: Yes, I tried debugging. But consider the fact that I am a newbie. @Quimby

Comment: I usually don't do that, but in this case I had to. Check line after the commented for loop. You'll understand why I did it. @fabian

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Both are not equivalent, if you look at this:

```
while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > element)
{
    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
    j = j - 1;
}
```

It stops as soon as `arr[j] > element`. But this does not:

```
for(  ; j >= 0 ; j--)
    {
        if(arr[j] > element){
            arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
        }    
        
    }
```

As it continue to run beyond `arr[j] > element`. So the equivalent will be:

```
for(  ; j >= 0 && (arr[j] > element) ; j--)
    {
       arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
    }
```

Answer (score 4):

Your while and for loops aren't equivalent. With your for loop, j always end up at 0 because there is no equivalence to the `&& arr[j] > element` check. This corrupts the vector content because you'll overwrite index 0.

Equivalent for loop:

```
for(  ; j >= 0 && arr[j] > element; j--)
{
    arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
}
```

Comment: You don't need the `if` in your code snippet. The loop condition evaluating to true implies that the `if` condition evaluates to `true` too. The compiler would likely optimize this out automatically, but adding unnecessary "noise" to the code isn't a good thing.

Comment: Derp. Correct. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

The loops are written with different logical conditions of break. Look at **while**:

```
while (j >= 0 && arr[j] > element)
```

This loop will break when `j` is lower than `0` *or* the `arr[j]` is lower than `element`. So if you meet the first `element` that is equal to/higher than `arr[j]`, the loop will break.

And now let's see the **for** loop:

```
for(  ; j >= 0 ; j--)
```

In this case the only condition is the countdown of value `j`. But if you find the `element` equal to / higher than `arr[j]`, meaning this won't be fulfilled:

```
if(arr[j] > element){
```

the loop will continue anyways until `j` isn't lower than `0`.

What would repair your code snippet is adding `break` instruction:

```
for ( ; j >= 0; j--) {
    if(arr[j] > element) {
        arr[j + 1] = arr[j];
    } else {
        break; // the loop will stop, just like the while loop does
    }
}
```

Comment: edit: I messed up the break condition - it should be executed when `if` requirements are not met